FastAPI path parameter translation to enumaration member
I started to learn FastAPI by reading the official documentation. I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding the example which illustrate how to work with Python enumarations. The example in the official documentation is a follows:
from enum import Enum

from fastapi import FastAPI


class ModelName(str, Enum):
    alexnet = "alexnet"
    resnet = "resnet"
    lenet = "lenet"


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/models/{model_name}")
async def get_model(model_name: ModelName):
    if model_name is ModelName.alexnet:
        return {"model_name": model_name, "message": "Deep Learning FTW!"}

    if model_name.value == "lenet":
        return {"model_name": model_name, "message": "LeCNN all the images"}

    return {"model_name": model_name, "message": "Have some residuals"}

The documentation says that: "The value of the path parameter will be an enumeration member."
I don't understand how the path parameter is an enumration member. For me the path parameter will correspond to the enumration value. When I call the endpoint 127.0.0.1:8000/models/alexnet, the path parameter alexnet is the value of the Enum member ModelName.alexnet. I'm not passing the Enumaration object in any way in the request.
So, I'm curious to understand when and how FastAPI makes the "translation" to the enumaration member from the path parameter in the call. Because it seems that the path parameter alexnet is implicitly translated to ModelName.alexnet.
UPDATE: What I also found counter-intuitive is that, if I change the Enum member as ALEXNET = "alexnet" and change the condition to if model_name is ModelName.ALEXNET: (i.e., in capital letters), I can still call the endpoint with 127.0.0.1:8000/models/alexnet(in lowercase, which is how the Enum value is defined).

You may find this answer helpful as well.

In the following line, you are adding the type-hinting to the path parameter. The path parameter has decoration with the app.get FastAPI decorator to wrap and call the function with the path parameter when the route is called.
@app.get("/models/{model_name}")
async def get_model(model_name: ModelName):

In your enumeration you're using, you have mapped the enumeration value as a string to the enumeration member.
class ModelName(str, Enum):
    alexnet = "alexnet"

When you call the endpoint with 127.0.0.1:8000/models/alexnet, FastAPI takes the path parameter “alexnet”, recognizes it as a valid ModelName Enum member, and converts it to ModelName.alexnet. This conversion happens because of the type hinting, which triggers FastAPI’s internal validation and conversion as part of handling the request. The string passed in is converted from the enum value to the enum member, and the decorated function is called with the enum member as the model_name argument.
If you were to call the endpoint with an invalid value, say 127.0.0.1:8000/models/invalid, FastAPI would return a validation error indicating that “invalid” is not a valid ModelName, responding to the request with a 422 Unprocessable Entity by default.

Thanks. What I found counter-intuitive is that, if I change the Enum member as ALEXNET = "alexnet" and change the condition to if model_name is ModelName.ALEXNET: (i.e., in capital letters), I can still call the endpoint with 127.0.0.1:8000/models/alexnet(in lowercase, which is how the Enum value is defined).

@glpsx Yes, this is exactly how it works! It matches values of enum, not the "keys". "Keys" are just a convenient name to use in your code (and it should be uppercase according to the standards).
